# Update another property, when a property changes?

Tags: javascript, oop, properties

I want to create a dependent property on my javascript object.
I have an object like in the code snippet. I want to update isPawn property; when isNew property changes.

Is there a way for do something similar that automatically;

```
if(isNew){
   isPawn = true;
}
```

But they are not have to be same. isNew can be 'false', when isPawn is 'true'

My Object:

```
var Soldier = function (id,name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isPawn = false;
    this.isNew = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using a setter, here is an example:

```js
class Soldier {
  #isNew = false;
  constructor(id,name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isPawn = false;
  }

  set isNew(val) {
    this.#isNew = val; 
    this.isPawn = val;
  }

  get isNew() {
    return this.#isNew;
  }
}

const soldier = new Soldier();
soldier.isNew = true;
console.log('isNew:', soldier.isNew, 'isPawn', soldier.isPawn);
soldier.isNew = false;
console.log('isNew:', soldier.isNew, 'isPawn', soldier.isPawn);
soldier.isPawn = true;
console.log('isNew:', soldier.isNew, 'isPawn', soldier.isPawn);
```

`#isNew` is a [private field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_instance_fields) in this case I'm using it to keep track of what the value of `isNew` should be (what the getter should return).

Here is an example using a function instead of a class:

```js
var Soldier = function(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.isPawn = false;
  this.isNewPriv = false;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'isNew', {
    set: function(val) {
      this.isNewPriv = val;
      this.isPawn = val;
    },
    get: function() {
      return this.isNewPriv
    }
  });
}

var soldier = new Soldier(1, 'none');
soldier.isNew = true;
console.log("isNew:", soldier.isNew, "isPawn:", soldier.isPawn);
soldier.isNew = false;
console.log("isNew:", soldier.isNew, "isPawn:", soldier.isPawn);
soldier.isPawn = true;
console.log("isNew:", soldier.isNew, "isPawn:", soldier.isPawn);
```

Comment: I think this is (getter/ setter) the solution. But this # thing confused me. What is it for?

Comment: @İkbal_BLGNR I've edited the question with some details about that.

Comment: @İkbal_BLGNR I've added an example extending your current function, maybe that is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class and instantiate as needed

```js
class Soldier {
  constructor(id, name, isNew) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isPawn = isNew? true : {something : "whaterverElse"};
    this.isNew = isNew;
  }
  
  DoSomething(){
    this.isNew = false;
  }
  
}

var soldier = new Soldier(1, 'Tim', true);

console.log(soldier);

function somethingElseHappened(){
  soldier.DoSomething();
}

somethingElseHappened();

console.log(soldier);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a default values for this properties like this:

```
var Soldier = function (id,name,isPawn = false,isNew = false) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isPawn = isPawn;
    this.isNew = isNew;
}
```

and if you want to change there values to any object for you just do like this:

```
var newSolider = new Solider(1,"foo",false,true);
```

Comment: When isNew property changes; is isPawn property gonna change automatically??

Comment: No, it will not

Comment: they have not be the same, also they have not be differ. so I think these a best way